# symfony2 custom time choice field

Tags: php, datetime, symfony, symfony-2.1

I'm trying to make custom datetime form fields.
Like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11449556/datatransformer-split-datetime-into-two-fields) i have split datetime fields with one date form field and on time form field using a DataTransformer.

I use a jquery datepicker for date selection, but i want to have ONE custom choice form field for time selection whith half hours intervalls:

```
00:00
00:30
...
23:30
```

Here is my code but i'm not sure how to approach this

In my entity

```
/**
 * Time
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="time")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Time
{

...

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="begin_date", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $beginDate;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="end_date", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $endDate;

...

    /**
     * Set beginDate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $beginDate
     * @return Time
     */
    public function setBeginDate($beginDate)
    {
        $this->beginDate = $beginDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get beginDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */

        public function getBeginDate()
    {
        $this->beginDate;
    }

    /**
     * Set endDate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $endDate
     * @return Time
     */
    public function setEndDate($endDate)
    {
        $this->endDate = $endDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get endDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getEndDate()
    {
        return $this->endDate;
    }

...

}
```

The form type

```
class TimeType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('beginDate', 'my_datetime', array('label' => 'label.form.date'))
        ->add('endDate', 'my_datetime', array('label' => 'label.form.date'));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'Time';
    }
}
```

So here is my custom form type:

```
 class MyDateTimeType extends AbstractType
{

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
    ->add('date', 'genemu_jquerydate', array('input'  => 'datetime','widget' => 'single_text','format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy','error_bubbling' => true))
    ->add('time', 'choice', array(
        'choices'   => array(
            '00:00' => '00:00',
            '00:30' => '00:30',
            '01:00' => '01:00',
...
            '22:30' => '22:30',
            '23:00' => '23:00',
            '23:30' => '23:30',
            ),'error_bubbling' => true
));

    $builder->appendClientTransformer(new DateTimeToDateTimeArrayTransformer());
}

public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
{
    return array(
        'label' => 'label.form.date',
        'error_bubbling' => false
        );
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'my_datetime';
}
}
```

And this is the DataTransformer:

```
class DateTimeToDateTimeArrayTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
public function transform($datetime)
{
    if(null !== $datetime)
    {
        $date = clone $datetime;
        $date->setTime(12, 0, 0);

        $time = clone $datetime;
        $time->setDate(1970, 1, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        $date = null;
        $time = null;
    }

    $result = array(
        'date' => $date,
        'time' => $time
    );

    return $result;
}

public function reverseTransform($array)
{
    $date = $array['date'];
    // $time = $array['time']; // Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object
    $time = new \DateTime($array['time']);

    if(null == $date || null == $time)
        return null;

    $date->setTime($time->format('G'), $time->format('i'));

    return $date;
}
}
```

Form display is correct, but when i submit the form i get this error:

> Notice: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to int in /var/www/ttime/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/ChoiceList/ChoiceList.php
>   line 457 
>   500 Internal Server Error - ErrorException

Whereas i have the split items datetime + custom choice correctly persisted to DB.

I think that the **reverseTransform** function return datetime format, and the form builder can't convert it to the choice format:

> array('00:00' => '00:00',...)

Can you tell me how can get rid of this error?

Is there a better way for doing this?

Comment: Probably your entity or database where you are storing the date is defined as an INT. Why don't you copy them into your question?

Comment: I've update the question, entity's objects are datetime objects

Answer (score 2):

The array of data returned by your datatransformers transform function is an array of DateTime objects. These objects can not be converted to choice-field values. To fix this return the actual formated date and time strings:

```php
$result = array(
    'date' => $date->format('Y-m-d'),
    'time' => $time->format('H:i')
);
```

Also the reverseTransform function should then convert these strings back to an actual DateTime object, using the following code:

```php
$dateTimeString = $array['date'] . ' ' . $array['time'];
return DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i', $dateTimeString);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it still doesn't work:
If i use this in transform function
`        $result = array(
    'date' => $date->format('Y-m-d'),
    'time' => $time->format('H:i')
);`
 this error appear: Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object

Comment: If i use this in transform:
`        $result = array(
            'date' => $date,
            'time' => $time
        );`

And this in reverseTRansform:
`        $dateTimeString = $array['date'] . ' ' . $array['time'];
        return DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i', $dateTimeString);`

This error appear: Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string