# Form with DataTime field split into two fields

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3

I want to split a DateTime field into two fields (date and time) using Symfony 2.3. Therefore I tried to adapt the Symfony 2.0 solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13691338/1526162) and made the necessary changes for Symfony 2.3.

the new type:

```
class MyDateTimeType extends AbstractType
{
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $builder
    ->add('date', 'date', array(
      'label'  => 'label.form.date',
      'input'  => 'datetime',
      'widget' => 'single_text',
      'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
      'error_bubbling' => true
    ))
    ->add('time', 'time', array(
      'label'  => 'label.form.time',
      'input'  => 'datetime',
      'widget' => 'single_text',
      'error_bubbling' => true
    ))
    ->addViewTransformer(new DateTimeToDateTimeArrayTransformer());
  }

  public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
  {
    return array(
      'label' => 'label.form.date',
      'error_bubbling' => false
    );
  }

  public function getParent()
  {
    return 'form';
  }

  public function getName()
  {
    return 'my_datetime';
  }
}
```

and the DataTransformer:

```
class DateTimeToDateTimeArrayTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
  public function transform($datetime)
  {
    if ($datetime instanceof \DateTime)
    {
      $date = clone $datetime;
      $date->setTime(12, 0, 0);

      $time = clone $datetime;
      $time->setDate(1970, 1, 1);
    }
    else
    {
      $date = null;
      $time = null;
    }

    $result = array(
      'date' => $date,
      'time' => $time
    );

    return $result;
  }

  public function reverseTransform($array)
  {
    $date = $array['date'];
    $time = $array['time'];

    if(null == $date || null == $time)
      return null;

    $date->setTime($time->format('G'), $time->format('i'));

    return $date;
  }
}
```

services.yml

```
foo.bar.form.type.my_date_time:
    class: Foo\Bar\Form\MyDateTimeType
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: my_datetime }
```

But when I use the type in a form like this:

```
$builder->add('abc', 'my_datetime', array(
    'label' => 'ABC',
    'data' => new \DateTime(null, new \DateTimeZone('UTC'))
));
```

I get the error:

The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class DateTime, but i a(n) array. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms a(n) array to an instance of DateTime.

Answer (score 8):

I know a bit late, but I had the same problem and solved it.

You don't need a new form type to split date and time of a datetime field.

In your form

```
$builder
    ->add('datetime', DateTimeType::class, array(
        'date_widget' => 'single_text',
        'time_widget' => 'single_text',
        'date_format' => 'dd.MM.yyyy',
        'required' => true,
    ))
:
```

And if you want to render the input fields seperatly (to add different classes as attributes for example), just do this in the twig template

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
.. 
{{ form_widget(form.datetime.date) }}
{{ form_widget(form.datetime.time) }}
..
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Tested in Symfony 2.6, should work from 2.3 upwards (maybe even 2.1)

edit: adjusted for Symfony 2.8 and higher

Comment: Perfect, saved me from creating hideous solutions